# ElasticSearch & Nest - Wrong convertion

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have this pure call to Elastic that works. It returns 29 docs:

```
GET /idxsearch-test/movies/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
            "must": {
                "bool" : { 
                  "should": [ 
                                {"term": {"tag.name": "Paris"}},
                                {"multi_match" : {
                                  "operator":   "and",
                                    "query" : "Paris",
                                    "fields": ["movie_title.default^10",
                                    "movie_title.snowball^2",
                                    "movie_title.shingles^2",
                                    "movie_title.ngrams"]}}
                            ] 
                }
            }, 
            "filter": {
              "term": { "is_adult": false }
            }
        }
  },
  "_source": ["id_content", "movie_title", "vote_average", "tag.name", "is_adult"]
}
```

I need to use Nest, so I converted to this. It returns 0:

```
        var vod = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
                            .Size(10)
                            .From(1)
                            .Index(defaultIndex)
                            .Type("movies")
                            .Query(qry1 => qry1
                                            .FunctionScore(fs =>
                                                    fs.Query(qry2 =>
                                                                qry2.Bool(bool1 =>
                                                                            bool1.Must(must1 =>
                                                                                        must1.Bool(bool2 =>
                                                                                                    bool2.Should(should1 =>
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        QueryContainer qc = null;
                                                                                                        qc &= should1.Term(tt => tt.Field("tag.name").Value(keywords));
                                                                                                        qc &= should1.MultiMatch(mm1 => mm1.Fields(ff => ff
                                                                                                                                                        .Field("movie_title.default^10")
                                                                                                                                                        .Field("movie_title.snowball^2")
                                                                                                                                                        .Field("movie_title.shingles^2")
                                                                                                                                                        .Field("movie_title.ngrams"))
                                                                                                                                        .Operator(Operator.And)
                                                                                                                                        .Query(keywords));

                                                                                                        return qc;
                                                                                                    })
                                                                                                  )
                                                                                       )
                                                                            .Filter(fil =>
                                                                            {
                                                                                QueryContainer query = null;
                                                                                if (!includeAdult)
                                                                                    query &= fil.Terms(fil2 => fil2.Field("is_adult").Terms(false));

                                                                                return query;
                                                                            })
                                                                        )
                                                           )
                                            .BoostMode(FunctionBoostMode.Sum)
                                            .Functions(ff => ff.FieldValueFactor(fv => fv.Field("vote_average")
                                                                                        .Factor(0.5)
                                                                                        .Modifier(FieldValueFactorModifier.Log1P)))
                            ))
                );
```

But the results are different... What am I missing?

Is there a way to make the same call in a cleaner and correct way?

cheers

Comment: Sorry but the two queries seam to be completely different? Are you just trying to write the first with nest?

Comment: @FilipCordas Hi. Yes, but they are not so different, in the Nest one there is the Score stuff that I took off of the plain json post. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query can be written as

```
//Fluent
            client.Search<dynamic>(
                s => s.
                Index("idxsearch-test").
                Type("movies").
                Take(20).
                Query(q => q.Bool(
                              b => b.Must(m => m.Term(t => t.Field("tag.name").Value("Paris")) ||
                                              m.MultiMatch(mm => mm.Fields(f => f.
                                                                              Field("movie_title.default", 10).
                                                                              Field("movie_title.snowball", 2).
                                                                              Field("movie_title.shingles", 2).
                                                                              Field("movie_title.ngrams")))).
                                      Filter(f => includeAdult ? f.Term(t => t.Field("is_adult").Value("")) : null))).
                 Source(sc => sc.Includes(i => i.Field("id_content").Field("movie_title").Field("vote_average").Field("tag.name").Field("is_adult"))));

            //Object
            client.Search<dynamic>(new SearchRequest<dynamic>("idxsearch-test", "movies")
            {
                Size = 20,
                Query = new BoolQuery
                {
                    Must = new QueryContainer[]
                    {
                        new BoolQuery
                        {
                            Should = new QueryContainer[]
                            {
                                new TermQuery() { Field = "tag.name", Value = "Paris" },
                                new MultiMatchQuery
                                {
                                    Fields = new [] { "movie_title.default^10", "movie_title.snowball^2", "movie_title.shingles^2", "movie_title.ngrams" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Filter = includeAdult ? new QueryContainer[]
                    {
                        new TermQuery { Field = "is_adult", Value = false }
                    } : null
                },
                Source = new Union<bool, ISourceFilter>(new SourceFilter { Includes = new[] { "id_content", "movie_title", "vote_average", "tag.name", "is_adult" } })
            });
```

Comment: Looks like its working... just a simple question... in the end, Nest will just mount a pure json and post to the server. So if I make the json and post, will be the same thing, thw only difference would be that the compiler wont lose any millisecond processing Nest stuff..correct? cheers.

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR It's just a nicer interface for writing the query but it will just do a LowLevel call with a Json string in the end. I don't think performance will be a problem but who knows there might be a tone of garbage collection needed to clean it all up. Also this might  help protect you from some sort of injection attack.